# Separate data in excel cells with separator as";"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have columns in excell with data in format A1=a;b;c and i want to divide it into three cells as B1=a,C1=b & D1=c . Please help

Comment: Use the text-to-columns wizard on the Data Ribbon

Comment: use the delimited setting and select ; as your delimiter.  Also select B1 or column B as your destination if you dont want your source over written.

Answer (score 1):

If you are continually pasting information into the A column and you are looking for a formula solution, you could do this

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",LEN($A1))),(COLUMNS($B:B)-1)*LEN($A1)+1,LEN($A1)))
```

That assumes your first bit of Data starts in cell A1 and you are placing your separated values starting in column B.  Copy the formula to the right as for as many entries as you have.

The simpler method is to use [Excel's text to columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-cells-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) option if it is available to you as pointed out by Ron Rosenfeld.

Comment: Your formula works like a charm. It seems to be much better approach than Text To Columns and may be for many who are not comfortable in using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a VBA solution. Please try this :

```
Sub Transpose_Q8582()
    Dim pasteRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

       With ActiveSheet
        Set pasteRng = .Range("B1:D1")
        With .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            For i = 1 To .Rows.Count Step 3
               pasteRng.Offset(i - 1).Value = Application.Transpose(.Cells(i, 1).Resize(3))
            Next i
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Snapshot shows the results:]

**EDIT**
There was an oversight in understanding OP requirement. I have revised VBA code to meet OP requirement.

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim values As Variant
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        values = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ";")
    Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(values) + 1).Value = values
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: Snapshot showing results]

Comment: I think you missed an important part of the question ... `A1=a;b;c`, not `A1=a`, `A2=b`, `A3=c`.

Comment: @OldUgly Sorry it is oversight. How can one withdraw his answer?

Comment: @skkakkar why withdraw, fix your answer 8) you can do it!  If you can't due to other commitment, hit delete instead of edit.  You can always undelete your answer later when you have it updated.

Comment: @Forward Ed Thanks for your kind advice. It was my commitment to some other important issue which was an obstacle. Somehow I could squeeze time to edit may answer and I think it is in line with OP requirement.

Comment: @OldUgly It is nice of you to have pointed out the mistake timely. Somehow I squeezed time to revise my answer in line with OP requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Select your intended cell(s) > Go to Data Menu > Text To Columns > Delimited > Choose semicolon >
>   Finish

Answer (score 0):

Write this formula in B1 and drag it towards right and for below rows

```
=IF(COLUMN()=2,LEFT($A1,1),IF(COLUMN()=3,MID($A1,3,1),RIGHT($A1,1)))
```